# rint() issue after creating VS Project using CMake

Tags: c, visual-c++, cmake, c99, cmake-gui

I'm having an issue compiling code - specifically [METIS - Serial Graph Partitioning and Fill-reducing Matrix Ordering](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/fetch/sw/metis/metis-5.1.0.tar.gz).

I've successfully managed to make Visual Studio 2013 Project out of the source files two ways: using CMake GUI (version 3.4.3) and using Command Line.

However, in both cases when I try to build the created project in Visual Studio, I'm getting an error: `Error C2059: syntax error : '('` on line

```
_CRTIMP double __cdecl rint(_In_ double _X);
```

where `_CRTIMP` is defined this way:

```
#define _CRTIMP __declspec(dllimport)
```

Is this issue caused in the process of creating Visual Studio Project by CMake, or is it a issue in source files of METIS?

Comment: Hm, what about searching through the metis source code?

Comment: I tried to search through the source code, but I didn't manage to locate the possible mistake. I don't understand, why there could be a problem with '(' on mentioned line. macro `_CRTIMP` is used a lot of times in the whole file and `rint()` is default function defined as `#define rint(x) ((int)((x)+0.5))`

Comment: I don't know, and this is really stabbing in the dark, but please be aware of VS, especially in older versions, not being C99-compatible at all.

Comment: @T.Brown Well, if `rint(x)` is really a macro, then of course it does not compile... the given line is expanded by the preprocessor to:   
`__declspec(dllimport) double __cdecl ((int)((_In_ double _X)+0.5));`

Comment: Also, as Marcus mentioned, VisualC++ is a C++ compiler. You would probably need a C compiler to compile C . I also tried compiling standard C, or GNU C before with Visual C++ , and gave up after a lot of frustration. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 4):

go to : metis\GKlib\gk_arch.h and metisbin.h and metislib.h. Remove or rename #define rint(x) ((idx_t)((x)+0.5)) it's causing a conflict with the rint function in math.h.

Answer (score 1):

only comment out the line `#define rint(x) ((idx_t)((x)+0.5))` in metis\GKlib\gk_arch.h is enough.