# install METIS library for python3 on windows7

Tags: python, visual-c++, installation, networkx, metis

I want to install METIS for python3.6 on windows7.I did the following steps:

1-Download the source (tar.gz or zip file) from 
  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx-metis/

2-Unpack and change directory to the source directory (it should have the 
  setup.py on top level).

3-Run

```
python setup.py build
```

to build

in this step, I encountered the following error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.
```

i installed "Visual Studio Tools 2017", Then I run the code again.  I encountered the following error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I would be very grateful if you answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Although what I used was Windows 10, perhaps the same steps as I laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675790/how-to-install-metis-package-in-python-on-windows) may work for you.

First, you should get the python metis wrapper using pip: `pip install metis`.

Second, **you must install conda-metis**, which you can find [here](https://github.com/menpo/conda-metis). Note, it does not require you to install Anaconda to work.

Place the files in conda-metis-master in some file path.

The installation requires some fixes. Make sure you have a recent version of Visual Studios (I used 2017). For me, VS had a problem running the instructions in BUILD-WINDOWS.txt, which landed me on this thread:

[Why does MSBuild look in C:\ for Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props instead of c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild? ( error MSB4019)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr)

Specifically, the answer **For Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 on Windows 10** was what I went with. It could potentially be different for you since you are on Windows 7.

For the python metis package, we need to generate a `metis.dll`, not a `metis.lib` file, so we must also look closer at the `CMakeLists.txt` (see the Linux version of this discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/592704/installing-python-wrapper-for-metis-cannot-locate-metis-dll-shared-library)). We add on line 19: `set(METIS_LIBRARY_TYPE SHARED)`.

You should follow the BUILD-WINDOWS.txt instructions, but run `.\vsgen -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` inside your conda-metis file path in command prompt with full permissions instead of using Visual Studio 10.

Before moving on to using the files that were generated by the above command in `path_to_your_metis_dir\build\windows\`, we need another fix. Following what was said in:

[rint() issue after creating VS Project using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562135/rint-issue-after-creating-vs-project-using-cmake)

we have to edit the file `path_to_your_metis_dir\GKlib\gk_arch.h` by removing the line: `#define rint(x) ((idx_t)((x)+0.5))`. (Or the fix listed on [this github exchange](https://github.com/jlblancoc/suitesparse-metis-for-windows/issues/19).)

Then go to `path_to_your_metis_dir\build\windows\`.

Open `METIS.sln` in Visual Studios, go to the top to `Build` and from the scroll-down go to `Build Solution`. Afterwards, the `.dll` file will be in `path_to_your_metis_dir\build\windows\libmetis\Release\`.

Last, we run in command prompt:
`set METIS_DLL=path_to_your_metis_dir\build\windows\libmetis\Release\metis.dll`

After this, python metis no longer failed when I would import it into my code with the step `from metis import *`.